# video presentation software using powerpoint and audio

Tags: video, powerpoint, video-capture

Hi I'm trying to create a video for my class that I need to upload to Vimeo or YouTube. I wan't to record my voice while I am doing a power point slide. So the video would be just powerpoint slides with my voice. Would someone suggest a software to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: -> http://superuser.com

Comment: Super User [won't love this question](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), @sled.

Comment: Isn't this a software related question? Powerpoint actually supports this feature: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/powerpoint-help/record-a-voice-narration-HP005195027.aspx

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Software recommendations SE would be a good place to ask a question of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, you'll want to post questions like this to SuperUser instead of StackOverflow (which is for programming related questions).

You don't say what version of PPT you have, but in 2010 or later, you can use PPT's Record Narration feature to record your voice-over and slide timings, then save as a movie for upload to YouTube etc.